# I'm starting with JS and I can't understand the mistake

Tags: javascript

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);//Do not touch, DARK MAGIC
var totalDamage = 0;

while(slaying)
{
    if(youHit)
    {
        console.log("Congrats you hitted the dragon");
    totalDamage += damageThisRound;

   if (totalDamage >= 4)
   {
       console.log("You Win!");
       slaying = false;
       }
    }
       else
       {
       youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
       }

} else {
        console.log("You weren't able to hit the Dragon");
    var slaying = false;}
}
```

I do not understand, i putted into a JS tester and told me that else is invalid.
It's important please help

Comment: What did the JS tester say?

Comment: Check the curly braces

Comment: You have very bad formatting, and there is a redundant brace in your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Comment: _"Do not touch, DARK MAGIC"_ ha ha ha no doubt you are really _"Starting with JS"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look with this identation and you'll see for yourself what the problem is:

```
    var slaying = true;
    var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);//Do not touch, DARK MAGIC
    var totalDamage = 0;

    while(slaying) {
        if (youHit) {
            console.log("Congrats you hitted the dragon");
            totalDamage += damageThisRound;

            if (totalDamage >= 4) {
                console.log("You Win!");
                slaying = false;
            }
        } else {
            youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
        }

    } else {
        console.log("You weren't able to hit the Dragon");
        var slaying = false;
    }
}
```

always maintain your code correctly indented and you'll avoid many problems

By the way: the DARK MAGIC part chooses randomly 0 or 1, which are equivalent to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you were trying to do:

```js
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); //Do not touch, DARK MAGIC
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
  if (youHit) {
    console.log("Congrats you hitted the dragon");
    totalDamage += damageThisRound;

    if (totalDamage >= 4) {
      console.log("You Win!");
      slaying = false;
    } else {
      youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    } else {
      console.log("You weren't able to hit the Dragon");
      var slaying = false;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem was too many curly braces in all the wrong places. To avoid this you should use correct code indentation. I included a [link](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079) that explains this in detail. Hope I helped!